# How to create a multiboot USB for installs

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot, grub2

I'm trying to boot various OS/Configurations of OS Install from a single USB. I've been using [Multisystem](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/), but it fails when I try to boot an install created with [RemasterSys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) + Ubuntu 11.04.

It gives something like "please provide a name for this disk".

I tried copying in the `./disk` folder into the directory for the install but it still fails.

Then I noticed that Ubuntu Desktop is boot directly via USB, so I copied the menu entry and modified the file names:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu Custom Install" {
    search --set -f "/customdist.iso"
    loopback loop "/customdist.iso"
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz root=UUID=E56C-B453 debian-installer/locale=en_US.UTF-8 debian-installer/language=en kbd-chooser/method=en console-setup/layoutcode=us console-setup/variantcode= console-setup/modelcode=pc105 iso-scan/filename=/customdist.iso boot=casper file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed noprompt text --
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

It gives something like file not found. I had `customdist.iso` under the root of the USB just like Ubuntu Desktop is. Also I noticed custom.seed is used so I changed that as well. What's wrong?

Do you have any advice on how to start using GRUB2? I never really get what the commands like `find`, `loopback` or what the long line `linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz ... file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed noprompt text --` do.

I suppose the simplest is just to learn to boot everything from ISO?

Comment: I've been looking into this myself and found http://www.panticz.de/MultiBootUSB but haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [recently posted](http://darknet.co.za/blog/multiple-operating-system-live-usb.html) how to create a bootable USB with grub 2 and multiple OS choices using the [MultiBootUSB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multibootusb/) shell script.

I can't guarantee it will work with your custom built RemasterSys install, but it's definitely worth a try and so far I'm pretty happy with my results. I have recreated my USB disk about 10 times now.

Comment: Link above to http://darknet.co.za/blog/multiple-operating-system-live-usb.html currently 404s.

Comment: Fails : require administrator rigths and download for Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

I made a detailed tutorial regarding creation of a [GRUB2 multiboot/multiISO LiveUSB](https://bitbucket.org/tlroche/install_resizable_encrypted_lmde/src/HEAD/create_LMDE_liveUSB.rst). Feel free to fork and make pull request(s)!